# Databases for compromised passwords that browsers use

Tags: passwords, web-browser, have-i-been-pwned

I am looking into databases of compromised passwords in order to ensure that passwords on a system I am responsible for are not already compromised.

To have complete peace of mind, I prefer to get access to the data, and check passwords locally, rather than sending hashed passwords to an API.

[HaveIBeenPwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) is an obvious one that came to mind. However, the main browsers Chrome, Safari and Firefox all automatically check saved passwords against a list of compromised passwords.

Does anyone know if these browsers use a database different from the one HaveIBeenPwned uses?

Comment: BTW the HIBP API doesn't take hashed passwords, but hash prefixes, so its use shouldn't reveal your password. See https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#SearchingPwnedPasswordsByRange. You can use padding if you're concerned about encrypted traffic analysis, see https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#PwnedPasswordsPadding.

Comment: Questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic in the same way that product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @BrunoRohée thanks for highlighting this. I am not sold on search by range/k-anonymity. It still open users to a little bit of risk. I'll admit it's very small, but the effort to download the full database is not too great either.

Comment: Concur. When the entire corpus can be downloaded *including frequency data*, and with 99.97% of them already cracked and publicly available, and with the K-anonymity at the prefix length used by HIBP ... you can pretty easily narrow down which password is most likely: the one with that prefix, that's also the most common in the HIBP corpus. Testing this for yourself with a given common password - querying the API, then sorting the results by HIBP frequency - is eye-opening. You don't even need the entire corpus - just crack the API results.

Comment: The way how the password checker integrated in Google Chrome is works if for example shown here: https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html It uses a technique called "private set intersection with blinding" that allows to check username and password on server side for matches without being able to reveal the original values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it seems very likely that large, well-resourced, security-conscious orgs (such as Google) would maintain their own corpus of commonly compromised passwords.

I would also expect that they would keep it privately held.

Comment: That's a reasonable line of thoughts. Sometimes though, they do share things for the greater good (or marketing points, if you're more on the cynical side).